# regular expression, how to replace a part of a text preserving its length

Tags: google-bigquery

I have, in a database, records that are serialized PHP strings that I must obfuscate emails if there are any. The simplest record is like `{s:20:"pika.chu@pokemon.com"}`. It is basically saying: this is a string of length 20 which is `pika.chu@pokemon.com`. This field can be kilobytes long with lot of emails (or none) and sometimes it is empty.

I wish I could use a SQL regular expression function to obfuscate the user part of the email while preserving the length of the string in order not to break the PHP serialization. The example email above shall be turned into `{s:20:"xxxxxxxx@pokemon.com"}` where the number of `x` matches the length of `pika.chu`.

Any thoughts?

Here is a more complete example of what can be found as serialized PHP:

```
a:4:{s:7:"locales";a:3:{i:0;s:5:"fr_FR";i:1;s:5:"de_DE";i:2;s:5:"en_US";}s:9:"publisher";s:18:"john@something.com";s:7:"authors";a:2:{i:0;s:21:"william@something.com";i:1;s:19:"debbie@software.org";}s:12:"published_at";O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2022-01-26 13:05:26.531289";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"UTC";}}
```

Comment: please provide sample with field having multiple emails

Comment: I have update my question with a more complete example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do it using native functions but it not worked because functions like `REGEXP_REPLACE` don't let you manipulate the match to get the size of it, for example.

Instead, I've created a UDF to do that:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION hideEmail(str STRING)
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE js AS """
  return str
          .replace(/([a-zA-Z.0-9_\\+-:]*)@/g, function(txt){return '*'.repeat(txt.length-1)+"@";})
  """;


  select hideEmail('a:4:{s:7:"locales";a:3:{i:0;s:5:"fr_FR";i:1;s:5:"de_DE";i:2;s:5:"en_US";}s:9:"publisher";s:18:"john@something.com";s:7:"authors";a:2:{i:0;s:21:"william@something.com";i:1;s:19:"debbie@software.org";}s:12:"published_at";O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2022-01-26 13:05:26.531289";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"UTC";}}')
```

Result:

```
a:4:{s:7:"locales";a:3:{i:0;s:5:"fr_FR";i:1;s:5:"de_DE";i:2;s:5:"en_US";}s:9:"publisher";s:18:"****@something.com";s:7:"authors";a:2:{i:0;s:21:"*******@something.com";i:1;s:19:"******@software.org";}s:12:"published_at";O:8:"DateTime":3:{s:4:"date";s:26:"2022-01-26 13:05:26.531289";s:13:"timezone_type";i:3;s:8:"timezone";s:3:"UTC";}}
```